# What is the smallest positive value of K which makes the closed-loop system unstable?

Tags: control-theory

You are given a transfer function $\displaystyle G(s)=\frac{1.81K(s+20)}{(s^3+10s^2+32s+32)}$. This system is connnected with unity negative feedback.

I've tried so many things but I can't do it .
I've did $1.81K(s+20)=0$, but it's clearly wrong.
I've got the zeros for the bottom part $($ $s=-2$ or $s=-4$ or $s=-4$).

So, $\frac{1.81K(s+20)}{s+2}\times \frac{1}{(s+4)^2}$.

Tried to equal the first one to zero, got nothing. I really don't know what to do .

Comment: Are you familiar with the Routh criterion?

Answer (score 4):

The transfer function of the system with unit negative feedback is $\frac{G(s)}{1+G(s)}$. The denominator is $q(s) =s^3+10 s^2 + 32 s + 32 + 1.81 K (s + 20)$.

The solution is to look for the smallest value of $K$ that makes $q(s)$ have a root in the right half plane (i.e. the real part of a root is positive). You can do this numerically (try different values of $K$, say in increments of $10^-2$ from $0$ onwards), or use a root locus chart or something.

As pointed out in a comment, the [Routh-Hurwitz stability criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routh%E2%80%93Hurwitz_stability_criterion) is another good option.

Comment: How do I do it?

Comment: I have 2 variables

Comment: I've edited the answer with two suggestions. Take some time to think about it, given that I just gave you the right problem formulation and you spent less than a minute considering it.

Comment: Around 15 was what I got